# Equivalent to "map $status status_title status_desc" in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I've been searching for a while for a way to have a map with the response code (`$status` variable) and a title and a description as values, so that I can have a map with all reponse codes (400, 401, [..], 500, 501, etc.) and use it in a static page (with SSI active) where I would do something like:

```
<h1><!--# echo var="status" default="" --> <!--# echo var="st
atus_title" default="Something is wrong" --></h1>
<p align="center"><!--# echo var=""status_desc" default="" --></p>
```

Currently I have two maps, as follows:

```
map $status $status_title {
  400 'Bad Request';
  401 'Unauthorized';
  [..]
}

map $status $status_desc {
  400 'The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error.';
  401 'The client must authenticate itself to get the requested response.';
  [..]
}
```

This is not working, although I get no error when checking the syntax with `nginx -t`. How could I combine these two maps into one so that I could get a custom error code, error title and error description in my error page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, the issue was not in the maps, but in a syntax error in the HTML template. The line:

```
<p align="center"><!--# echo var=""status_desc" default="" --></p>
```

Should read:

```
<p align="center"><!--# echo var="status_desc" default="" --></p>
```

It's now working as intended. I'll leave this for future reference.